# Odd TypeError from the airflow scheduler -- has usage of @once for scheduler interval changed in v1.9?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a super simple test DAG that looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='scheduler_test_dag',
  start_date=datetime(2017, 9, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0), #..EC2 time. Equal to 11pm hora México
  max_active_runs=1,
  schedule_interval='@once' #externally triggered
  )

def ticker_function():
    with open('/tmp/ticker', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format(datetime.now()))

time_ticker = PythonOperator(
    task_id='time_ticker',
    python_callable=ticker_function,
    dag=DAG
)
```

Since upgrading to `apache-airflow` v1.9 this DAG is hung and won't run. Digging into the scheduler logs I found the error trace:

```
[2018-02-12 17:03:06,259] {jobs.py:1754} INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['scheduler_test_dag']) retrieved from /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/scheduler_test_dag.py
[2018-02-12 17:03:06,315] {jobs.py:1386} INFO - Processing scheduler_test_dag
[2018-02-12 17:03:06,320] {jobs.py:379} ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 371, in helper
pickle_dags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1792, in process_file
self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1388, in _process_dags
dag_run = self.create_dag_run(dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 807, in create_dag_run
if next_start <= now:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() <= datetime.datetime()
```

Where is this error coming from? The only thing that I can think of is that the usage of `scheduler_interval='@once'` has changed, which is the one thing that this DAG has in common with one other broken DAG on my server since the v1.9 upgrade. Otherwise it's the most basic DAG ever--doesn't seem like there should be a problem. Previously I was using the basic pip install before switching to the `apache-airflow` repo.

Here's a screenshot of the Web UI. Everything seems to be working alright, except the top and bottom DAGS which have scheduling interval set to `@once` and are indefinitely hung:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Have you defined catch up as True in your airflow.cfg? Then this is fixed in master. Disable catchup for this dag and it should start working.

Comment: Set catch up to True in the config and and disable catchup in each individual DAG. No luck. And what's more, I'm getting this very weird "Unknown MySQL server host error" related to my meta DB. You've responded to a couple of my posts before -- would you or any member of the community be interested in a short, remote paid consulting engagement to help me iron this out? I see the potential of the tool but am consistently frustrated by how hard it is to get everything running.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and fixed it by setting ‘catchup=false’ on the dag object. It should be fixed in master as well by now

Comment: I have `catchup_by_default = False` in the `airflow.cfg`--do I also pass `catchup=false` into my DAG definition?

Comment: This still hasn't fixed the issue, yet. The jobs with `scheduler_interval=@once` are still totally hung

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related with this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1977

It is important to mention that this is only an issue while the task does not run at least once. For instance if you configure the task

```
schedule_interval=None
```

And manually run it once, it will work as expected. After that you can put `@once`as the `schedule_interval` and the scheduler won't complain again (of course that if you manually trigger a task it defeats the purpose of running automatically once...). I did not test if the same happens to the other tags or not but this could fix this same issue with for example the `@daily`tag.